# After upgrading magento 2.3 to 2.4.6, the media does not work

Tags: magento2.4.6

When performing `setup:upgrade`, it returns `Media files stored outside the "Allowed Media Gallery" folders will not be available for the media gallery. Please refer to the developer's guide for more details.`  and when I want to upload an image for a product, the error appears "Something went wrong when saving the file(s).
`
please help me, I don't understand why the media didn't work

Answer (score 0):

i found solutions for the upload image error, but still i need to know how add Media files to"Allowed Media Gallery" if any solution ?
Thanks
bellow the solution upload file error

in the  path  `veondor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter` in `Gd2.php` find
function `validateURLScheme` and replace

`if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes)) {`

to

`if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && strlen($url['scheme']) > 1 && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes)) {`